# Do you know of a javascript library that lets you embed textareas that update a webpages format in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, real-time, wysiwyg

I'm introducing some at-risk kids to HTML in an upcoming class and we have a very small amount of time to show them how cool making your own web page can be.

What I'd like to do is build a page template full of text boxes which the kids can fill with text and some simple formatting tags. As they update, a split screen would update with the results of their edits.

I'm looking for a free / open source jquery or other javascript library which would help achieve the goal above.

Actually, it would quite similar to what stackoverflow does in the preview box as you are typing a question.

Rather than just blindly lifting code from other websites, I would love something with actual documentation (or at least a quick example.)

Google searches show a lot of tools and things you can download or use on other sites. The ideal here would be a library I embed in a page and position as I see fit.

Thanks for your help

**Edit**

As pointed out by some folks - this is a simple matter of updating divs on certain events.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).keyup(function(){ 
        $('#about_me_result').html($('#about_me').val());
    });
</script>


<textarea id="about_me" name="aboutMe" rows="9" cols="60">Write a little something about you...</textarea>
```

I went with keyup since keydown always leaves the last character off the other element.

Comment: You could just capture the textarea's contents on the `onKeyup` event, and copy it into the other pane with JS and a container `<div>` for each textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real need for a library. Just update the document

```
$(window).keydown(function(){ 

    $('#element').html($('#sometextarea').val());
});
```

Comment: I do like this, I tried this and the jsfiddle idea below. The one in the fiddle didn't seem to do what I expected. Although that may be because it's contained in another page. I ended up trying what you wrote and saving it into a local file and I can see the updates as I type.

Answer (score 1):

As btown suggests in his reply below, you could just send them to jsfiddle.net.

Or, if you want to put something like that on your own page somewhere, you could cook your own! play around here: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/LD9kA/

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>


$('#code').keyup(function(e){
    $('#result').html($(this).val());
});
```

Or, maybe you want an "Update" button instead of updating on keyup.

```
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="update">Update</button>
<div id="result"></div>


$('#update').click(function(){
    $('#result').html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: In general, jsfiddle.net might be exactly what you want, if you're willing for them to hit "run" when they're done with an edit.

Comment: Not sure I'm keen on going to another site (found a bunch of those, although not this one - more geared towards JS than HTML) as I wanted to create a custom template for the kids to start with. You guys are right though, it might just be simpler to do the div updates myself. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

What about [w3c Schools Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic) it's much simpler than jsfiddle.

The only thing is you have to press a button to see the HTML update. That's probably not a bad thing though as if it changed on every key up the resulting web page might go crazy as you typed in half finished tags and attributes.